# SQL autoincrement in 'string'

Tags: mysql, sql, string, auto-increment

I know about autoincrement, and that I might be better off doing a table of its own for this, but for some specific performance reasons I would prefer not to.

I have a row looking like this:

```
id,log
1 | 1:345;2:2345;3:234
```

Is there ANY way where I with a single SQL update can add X to the log column, and automatically a '4' as the log entry's id?

Comment: Answer = yes...string functions can pull that off for you (might be a bit ugly?).  What Database are you on?  String syntax differs between SQL flavours

Comment: mysql currently, but at some point I wanna move it to nosql like mongodb or similar - but right now i dont wanna mess with a lot of software (just code, and I was curious :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I can't be entirely sure, but it looks like you don't even need the index numbers, i.e.

```
id | log
1  | 345;234;234
```

So you can simply add the entry, optionally prefixed with a `;`. Later, any code can interpret the `log` contents by splitting on `;`.

Comment: yeah you are completely right, what a nobrainer... Just got caught up in having it in a single field. Explode + count will do :)

Answer (score 0):

how about build a new table like this:

```
my_log
-------
id
sub_id
val
```

and populate it with all the proper parsed values -

then query from here to rebuild the string if needed, otherwise throw out the original table completely - terrible design.